# Cosa significa "censa"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Non eravamo gli ultimi della nostra parentela e se la facevano tutti abbastanza bene: chi aveva la **censa**, chi il macello gentile, chi un bel pezzo di terra propria.

Non ho trovato il vocabolo "censa" in nessun dizionario. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa? Si tratta di un termine di origine piemontese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ho trovato la risposta nel libro [*Come il letto di un falò: Riflessioni su Cesare Pavese*](https://books.google.es/books?id=G7JWAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&lpg=PT73&dq=censa+significato&source=bl&ots=0zLoLypzKv&sig=drT5wK3ZHjcxQHdeso7D96XFqrc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim4--W2tXbAhWqAMAKHYjdC5c4ChDoAQgQMAI#v=onepage&q=censa%20significato&f=false), di Franco Lorizio:

> Il sostantivo dialettale "censa" – tabaccheria – ricorre in una sola occasione: "mi vide davanti alla censa che guardavo le cartoline". Deriva dal latino "census", "appalto" e non sembra trovare  ampia diffusione in ambito regionale: il lemma non è presente nello "storico" *Vocabolario Piemontese–Italiano* di Michele Ponza, così come in altri dizionari consimili più recenti; compare invece nella *Raccolta ed origine di vocaboli tipici delle Valli Monregalesi* di Sergio Piazzo, cosa che potrebbe far pensare a un uso circoscritto al Piemonte meridionale.

La citazione di Pavese è del romanzo *La luna e i falò*.

Comment: Ho deciso di scrivere la domanda e la risposta perché penso possa essere utile ai lettori di questo libro, così come a quelli  di *La luna e i falò* di Pavese.

Comment: Infatti, il termine "censa" appare molte volte sul romanzo *La malora*.

Comment: Interessante. Anche in dialetto veneto (il dialetto dei miei nonni piuttosto che il mio, a dir la verità) esiste un italianismo, _apalto_, che significa _tabaccheria_.

Comment: Anche nel Canavese censa era un vocabolo usato per tabaccheria ancora negli anni 50-60

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato in *[Il sacrificio di Agostino](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/1f315a6f-f4dd-4e39-b59b-b01a40eefd5b)* da *La malora* la spiegazione di censa:

> censa: altra voce settentrionale, tabaccheria.